# Как сделать так, чтобы какое-то событие происходило через определённое время? java android

Tags: java, android, таймер, java-timertask, java-timer

Допустим есть переменная int a = 0;
мне нужно, чтобы каждую минуту эта переменная увеличивалась на единицу, как мне это реализовать?
и как мне реализовать, чтобы эта переменная увеличивалась на единицу, через случайный отрезок времени?

Comment: а что, если созранить определенный момент времени, например 2020-11-30 15:00:00, тогда, когда вам надо будет посчитать значение a, вам надо будет только узнать, сколько минут прошло от начального момента времени до текущего.

Comment: @tym32167, мне нужно, чтобы определённое событие, происходило через определённый (или случайный) отрезок времени

Comment: это звучит как таймер. Какие то проблемы с таймером?

Comment: Посмотрите AlarmManager. Или в отдельном потоке увеличивать с применением TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1). =)

Comment: @Crush AlarmManager не будет срабатывать через минуту

Comment: Можно широковещательным приемником принимать событие, которое отправляется системой каждую минуту

Comment: @Style-7 Проверил - действительно, даже с модификатором RTC срабатывает через близкие интервалы времени. Спасибо за уточнение!

Answer (score 0):

Создайте поток

```
int a = 0

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         // code
      });
    } 
}).start();
```

внутри тела run будет выполнятся код, поток которого может sleep(long)

например

```
a++
sleep(Long.random(1000..4000))
```

Когда нужно будет достать в основной поток сделайте в активити

```
runOnUiThread (new Thread(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() {
             // code
         }
}));
```